# Knox error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, knox-amazon-s3-client

I am getting following error while installing and setup of Knox on Hortonworks Hadoop 2.1.5.

I have already installed java jdk-7u65-linux-x64.tar.gz

```
SGSCAI0081:~ # su -l knox -c '/usr/lib/knox/bin/gateway.sh setup'
***************************************************************************************************
You have indicated that you would like to persist the master secret for this service instance.
Be aware that this is less secure than manually entering the secret on startup.
The persisted file will be encrypted and primarily protected through OS permissions.
***************************************************************************************************
Enter master secret:
Enter master secret again:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.gateway.launcher.Invoker.invokeMainMethod(Invoker.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.gateway.launcher.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.gateway.launcher.Command.run(Command.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.gateway.launcher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:69)
        at org.apache.hadoop.gateway.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:70)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.gateway.services.DefaultGatewayServices.init(DefaultGatewayServices.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.gateway.GatewayServer.main(GatewayServer.java:110)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
        ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to using Java 8 rather than Java 7. Even though you have installed Java 7 - perhaps you still have JAVA_HOME set to Java 8?